# jQuery SVG Line stroke-linejoin (edit: SVG markers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm drawing an arrow between two spots on the page. Each time this is called, the arrow is cleared and redrawn with different points. Right now the line is drawing correctly, but there is no arrow at the end. I'm using the [jQuery SVG plugin](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html)

```
var svg = $('#board').svg('get');
svg.clear();
var startX = fromCol*sideLen + sideLen/2;
var startY = fromRow*sideLen + sideLen/2;
var endX = toCol*sideLen + sideLen/2;
var endY = toRow*sideLen + sideLen/2;
svg.line(startX, startY, endX, endY, {
    strokeWidth: 5
    , stroke: 'yellow'
    , strokeLineCap: 'round'
    , strokeLineJoin: 'miter'
});
```

The camel-case variables are setting to the correct CSS properties, I double checked that. An example output of this code in the DOM is

```
`<line x1="375" y1="325" x2="325" y2="275" stroke-width="5" stroke="yellow" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="miter"></line>`
```

I'm stumped. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok, at this point I've realized that stroke-linejoin doesn't just magically make arrow points at the end of lines and that I'm looking to add a `marker` to the line. The jQuery SVG plugin [has a marker method](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html#marker) but I can't find any examples where this is actually used. I'm now researching how to do it using [svg.js](http://svgjs.com) or pure Javascript. Feel free to respond about any of the approaches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I define this in the setup:

```
$('#board').svg();
var svg = $('#board').svg('get');
// Adds a marker to the svg defs element
var defs = svg.defs();
var marker = svg.marker(defs, 'arrow', 3, 2, 5, 5, 'auto');
// Define the shape of the marker
svg.polyline(marker, [[0,0], [4,2], [0,4], [1,2]], {
    "fill"  : "yellow"
});
```

And call this when drawing the line, similar to earlier but with the new setting and an id.

```
var svg = $('#board').svg('get');
var g = svg.group({stroke: 'yellow', strokeWidth: 5});
svg.line(g, startX, startY, endX, endY, {
    "id" : "line"
    , "strokeLineCap" : "round"
    , "marker-end"  : "url(#arrow)"
});
```